# Pentium 4 shows as 2 processors?

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, intel-pentium

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 on a system having a Pentium 4 processor.

When I open system monitor and go to the resources tabs, and see the CPU usage history, it shows the graph in two different colors, one being for Processor 1 and second for Processor 2.

If it was for Core 2 Duo or i3, I would understand, but isnt the Pentium series supposed to be single core ? or it means something else when it says Processor 1 and Processor 2. Is it some sort of logical division !?

Comment: This question coudl easily have been answered by looking at the Pentium 4 product page on the Intel website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Pentium 4 is a single core processor but it has a technology called [Hyperthreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) which makes it appear as a dual core processor.

Basically the processor tries to make more efficient use of the multiple processing parts of the single core by pretending to be two processors so that when parts of the core are not being used by one thread then another thread can try to use to resources.

Answer (score 1):

Totally normal. Those are threads.
Also similar question has been asked here: [Click](http://www.overclock.net/t/797998/pentium-4-showing-2-cores)

Comment: For further explanation have a look here :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading